# Java | Slick2D - How to use Objects in TiLeD?

Tags: java, object, entity, slick2d

Hello I'm creating a game and I have a few ways to make trainers stand (because it's a Pokemon game) but then I have to code their positions every time as entities for each new map I make. Is there a way to make an object in TiLeD and then make Java automatically import all trainers?

Thanks!

EDIT: If there is a way, then please explain how?

Comment: Do you mean that you're hard-coding trainers' positions, as opposed to, say, saving them to a file, and reloading them when you switch maps? I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Can you clarify?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed the problem. Figured out how to load the objects layer from Tiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at the Slick2D forums - there's work on a a subclass of `TiledMap` called `TiledMapPlus` that is a lot more object-oriented, and less array-tastic.

Comment: I've looked high and low across the internet, and I still can't find where to get TiledMapPlus!!

Comment: @Arcym - I'll try to find a link when I get a moment.

Comment: Have you had any luck in finding it, @Deejay?

Comment: Did you find the link?